# Differential continuity equation for Fluid (conservation of mass)

Tags: continuity, fluid-dynamics

I know the equation can be written in this way:

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla  \cdot (\rho \vec{v})=0$$

How can i write this equation to 
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \rho \nabla  \cdot (  \vec{v})=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $\nabla \cdot (\rho \vec v)=\nabla (\rho) \cdot \vec v+\rho \nabla \cdot (\vec v)$.  If $\nabla \rho =0$, then

$$\nabla \cdot (\rho \vec v)=\rho \nabla \cdot (\vec v)$$

Note that $\nabla \rho =0$ implies that $\rho$ does not depend on the spatial coordinates.

Comment: Could you please give me an example that when a fluid can have this kind of situation?

Comment: @sabbirhasan That question is not a mathematical one.  But certainly as a function, $\rho$ can be strictly time dependent.